# Is there a way to stop xsi:type validation from Mule when we use mulexml:xslt-transformer?

Tags: xml, xslt, mule, mule-esb

Currently we are have an XSL translation and when we pass the source xml from Mule with mulexml:xslt-transformer, we get the below error in mule 3.9.5

Exception stack is:
Unknown xsi:type in element being validated: ... (net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException) (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException)

How do we switch off this validation? Currently this issue is not there with 3.9.0 mule CE. The moment I upgrade to 3.9.5 Mule CE, we encounter this error. Can some one help?

Comment: Please provide steps and data to reproduce the error.

Comment: And also the complete error log.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is nothing wrong with your data, schemas and XSL -you didn't share any details- this could be related to an issue in the library use by Mule to implement the XSLT transformation: https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/3062 that was not fully fixed in that library.

Unfortunatelly as Mule 3.9 is in sustaining mode, not expected to receive improvements until its end of life March 2024, and the Community Edition usually doesn't receive patches (3.9.5 seems to be an exception), there is not a simple way to resolve this issue.

Some alternatives could be:

- (Not recommended) Upgrade the Saxon libraries in Mule. There is a risk that the newer versions are not compatible or cause some unexpected behavior.
- (Recommended) [Migrate the application to Mule 4.4](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.4/index-migration) or later. You need to migrate the full application since Mule 3 and Mule 4 are not compatible. The Mule 4 [XML Module has an XSLT operation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/xml-module/1.4/xml-xslt) and uses a newer version of Saxon. Even a simple proof of concept test should tell you if it resolves the issue before attempting a full migration.